# Dispatcher timer tick event not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, dispatchertimer

I attached one delegate to Dispatcher timer Tick event which runs in every 500 ms its Working fine on my computer but when I run same application on another computer it's start for first time but never gets a hit on tick event again.
it's just running for one time only.
I want know is it possible if I have some exception in my delegate can it cause timer to misbehave?
How can I solve this problem?

This Timer runs throughout the lifecyle of application and stop only when application is stoped.

```
        tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
        tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        tmr.Tick += delegate
        {
            FaceRecognizer_Advanced.GetInstance.GetFacesFromImage();
        };
        tmr.Start();
```

I expect this timer should get hit the way it suppose to be.

Comment: " but when I run same application on another computer " what are the differences between the 2 computers?

Comment: Do you have same logger to get sure it is not called? Maybe it is called but it fails with exception / does nothing.

Comment: @MongZhu The second computer have bigger specifications. it was working fine before, it's just started misbehaving, when I run previous exe it runs fine. and whatever change we made are not even near that code.

Comment: @pwas Yes I am using a logger which update after every step or execption.